# coreAnimation memory allocation keeps growing

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, core-animation

I am an experience programmer, but a newbie to IOS trying to finish off a game and am having trouble with memory running away.

The problem I am seeing can be reproduced simply with al,most no custom code:  To simplify, I started with the out-of-the box apple sample project:  openGlGame, which produces a single view of spinning cubes.  I then added a startup view/controller in front of the spinning cube view/controller. I then added a button on each screen with a segue and an unwind, respectively, so I could go back and forth between a blank startup view, and the spinning cubes.

When profiling this project (using "Allocations"), every time I go back and forth between the views, the memory allocated for the coreAnimation object increases by over 10MB !!

This is roughly the same thing that is happening in my game.

Why is this memory running away?  Is there something overlooked in the sample project? Is there something I am overlooking?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't really help you without relevant pieces of code and preferably some information from Instruments with heap shots, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the false alarm. I was looking at "Overall Bytes" on Instruments, instead of "Live Bytes". Hopefully this will be helpful for someone.